# Making a method to insert data in different tables

Tags: java, mysql, insert, prepared-statement

I want to make a single method to make inserts on different tables, I want the user to
put as parameters the name of the table and a list of the data to be inserted.

Something like this:

```
public void insertar(String tabla, LinkedList data) 
{
    String alta = "insert into " + tabla + " values(";
    for(int i = 0; i < datos.size(); i++) {
        alta = alta + "?,";
    }
    alta = alta.substring(0, alta.length() - 1) + ")";
    System.out.println(alta);
    try 
    {
        PreparedStatement insertar = con.prepareStatement(alta);
    } 
    catch (SQLException ex) 
    {
    }
}
```

My problem is that I can't figure out how to set the values once the
String is made because the size and type of the data can change depending of
the table i'm using.

Is there a way to do this?, or I need to make it different?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your linked list should probably contain something other than `String`'s.  Have you considered creating a type of `Binding` class that knows how to go about setting the values on your preparedStatement?  I am envisioning something like this:

```
public abstract class Binding {
    public abstract void bind(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException;
}

public class IntegerBinding extends Binding {
    private int value;
    private int index;

    public IntegerBinding(int _index, int _value) {
        index = _index;
        value = _value;
    }

    public void bind(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
        ps.setInt(index, value);
    }
}
```

You can use the value you are trying to apply to the `PreparedStatement` and the index into the `PreparedStatement` to create your concrete `Binding` implementation.  Of course you would need to write your own `Binding` subclasses to encompass the other types of data you are interested in using.

Here is a slight modification to your code to be able to use the ideas above:

```
public void insertar(String tabla, List<Binding> bindings) 
{
    String alta = "insert into " + tabla + " values(";
    for(int i = 0; i < datos.size(); i++) {
        alta = alta + "?,";
    }
    alta = alta.substring(0, alta.length() - 1) + ")";
    System.out.println(alta);
    try 
    {
        PreparedStatement insertar = con.prepareStatement(alta);
        for(Binding binding : bindings)
        {
            binding.bind(insertar);
        }
        insertar.execute();
    } 
    catch (SQLException ex) 
    {
    }
}
```

I think that this is a pretty handy solution and I hope it will help you out.  Good Luck!

Comment: Ok I will implement this solution and see if it works. Thanks =)

Comment: Thank you very much I implemented this and it worked. Thanks a lot =)